# analog serial read values are not equal

Tags: serial, analogread

I have not used the Arduino in over 2 years and have forgotten a bunch of stuff I was wondering if someone could help me out. I have two analog sensors both the same connected to the appropriate analog pins. I am getting a read on the serial monitor and when i test the sensors the values are changing so i know the circuit is correct and everything is in the right place. I just have an issue with my code.

```
void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue1 = analogRead(A0);

  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.println(sensorValue1);
   //Serial.print("val1 = " );
  Serial.print(sensorValue1);
  Serial.print(" ");

  delay(1000);        // delay in between reads for stability


   // read the input on analog pin 1:
  int sensorValue2 = analogRead(A1);

  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.println(sensorValue2);
  //Serial.print("val2 = " );
  Serial.print(sensorValue2);
  Serial.print(" ");
  delay(1000);        // delay in between reads for stability

 }
```

once i view this in the serial monitor it is not organized and the sensorvalue1 is skipping over to the next line. I would appreciate the help.

[image: This is the serial output on the serial monitor]

There are two sensors so there should be two values but in the picture the values are all messed up i would ideally like it to give me a two seperate values one for each sensor

val1= sensorvalue1
val2= sensorvalue2

Comment: Can you paste here the serial monitor output that you get, and write what you would expect? Otherwise your question won't be very clear to everyone.

Comment: jfpoilpret i have updated my question thank you

Comment: The delays likely won't affect the stability, since the switching of the ADC pins into the multiplexer in `analogRead()` doesn't happen before the `delay()`.  If you switch pins with an extra `analogRead()` and throw away the value before the delay() you will get more stable readings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0 and 1 with delays for stability:
  delay(1000);       
  int sensorValue1 = analogRead(A0);
  delay(1000);        
  int sensorValue2 = analogRead(A1);

  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.print("val1 = " );
  Serial.print(sensorValue1);
  Serial.print(" val2 = " );
  Serial.println(sensorValue2);



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems like you are writing the value with a println(), and then again the value without new line but space. Then you write value2 with an ending newline and again value2 without newline. In your output there is also a string that does not match up anywhere in the code you posted. Double check what you are uploading and check if it has error.